# How much looping is too much? (PHP Do-While Loop)

Tags: php, loops, do-while

There may not really be an answer to this, but I'm wondering how much is too much when it comes to do-while loops.

For example, if it has to loop through 10 times, is that considered bad?  5 times?  Does it depend on the kinds of things the loop is doing?  Would there be a way to track the amount of "effort" (memory?) it's taking to execute the loop and use that to determine if it's ok or not?

This is more of an open-ended "discussion" as opposed to me looking or a specific answer.

Comment: It's more of the work than the actual number of loops. Say you have several heavy functions in a loop, that might be killing you in just a couple of repeats. While a loop with as little work possible (as they should be) might in theory run millions of times in a blink of an eye.

Comment: the only bad loop is an infinite one. you can use `memory_get_usage()` to see the amount of memory being used in your script.

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey: Any thoughts on how much memory is too much?

Comment: I would say it depends on what the loops are doing, if they aren't doing too much then 25 times through isn't bad at all, but if its doing large queries inside then you don't want to loop through too many times.

Comment: There is no definitive answer. There are infinite loops which are blocked by functions invoked within them (like http servers for example).

Comment: @gtilflm well you are going to hit pre-defined limits on your host that is set in your php.ini, you can increase this with `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');` in your script ... if you set it to high other scripts won't have enough memory to run.

Comment: My rule of thumb: if you know exactly how many times you need to loop, use a `for` loop.  If you don't kno use `while`.  `foreach` kinda falls in between.

Comment: Too much is `more than you need`: enough is `as much as you need`

Comment: Downvotes because........

Comment: `This is more of an open-ended "discussion" as opposed to me looking or a specific answer.` That's why you got downvotes. SO is a site for concrete programming questions with concrete programming answers. Read the FAQ please — you've been here for a year already.

Comment: So, it's not a place for learning (through asking questions)?  This is a legitimate question that's helpful for newish users in programming.  General questions can lead to specific answers for people in this kind of situation.  It's stupid to penalize in this case.

Comment: It's a place for learning when there is an answer that can be given, but not for discussion of open-ended questions for which there is no right or wrong answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For individual loops it really depends on what the code inside is doing, if it's taking too long to compute, or eating up piles of memory then you have to find that bit and change it. Realistically there's no upper limit on how many iterations a "good loop" does because it's "however many are necessary".

The real snag that's very easy to fall into is nested loops. eg:

```
for( $i=0; $i<100; $i++ ) {
    for( $j=0; $j<100; $j++ ) {
        for( $k=0; $k<100; $k++ ) {
             // some code       
        }
    }
}
```

It looks innocuous, but the code in the inner loop will be evaluated 1,000,000 times. Optimizing code like this for sorting/searching/etc isn't just an 'open-ended discussion' it's a vast portion of all Computer Science.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how it executes on the target machine. If you see a lot of lags in different modules (could be graphics, audio, etc), you may have to reduce the impact of such a loop through division of the loop (executing the loop on multiple iterations) or threading.

All in all, you need to try it out. If it behaves well, you're good to go. BUT, I would strongly suggest using a thread when it takes a long time like that so that you can send back progress information to the user.